# Extract values from JSON array

Tags: php, json, parsing, curl, decode

I have a problem with a decoded JSON response: I don't know how to extract every value from the JSON decoded array in PHP.

My script is like this:

```
$adresse= $_POST['address'];
$url = 'http://my/host/folder/api';
$data = array(
    "value" => $adresse,
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "some_user:somepassword");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
               array('Content-Type:application/json',
                     'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
               );
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json_response = var_dump(json_decode($resp, true));
echo 'test = '.$json_response[1]['zipcode'];
```

This code returns an array like this:

```
array(1) { 
    ["eligibilities"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(2) { 
            ["address"]=> array(5) { 
                ["zipcode"]=> string(5) "60000" 
                ["city"]=> string(9) "SomeCITY" 
                ["streetName"]=> string(17) "SomeSTreetName" 
                ["streetNumber"]=> string(2) "17" 
                ["idRA"]=> string(10) "SomeIDRA"
            }
            ["broadBand"]=> array(5) { 
                ["eligible"]=> bool(true) 
                ["type"]=> string(10) "SomeType" 
                ["maxDownstream"]=> int(20000) 
                ["maxUpstream"]=> int(1000) 
                ["tvEligible"]=> bool(false) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to parse every value in this array into variables so I can work with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that `var_dump` does not return a value, so when you do this:

```
$json_response = var_dump(json_decode($resp, true));
```

... then `$json_response` will be `null`.

To get access to these inner values, don't forget that there are multiple nested levels involved in your data, and you need to mention the key of each level. So do this:

```
$result = json_decode($resp, true);
var_dump($result);
echo 'test = ' . $result['eligibilities'][0]['address']['zipcode'];
```

NB: don't call your variable `$json_responce` after the `json_decode`, because then it is no longer JSON, but a native PHP array.